# How can I validate if the MySQL dump was restored correctly?

Tags: mysqldump

I am taking a backup on a live system where inserts are going on. The backup size is around 50 GB. I have started the restore of the backup but for some reason I have not enabled the log, and also my session terminated. How can I verify that restore was done successfully?

Before taking the backup I have even not calculated the data size, index size, or tables row counts. So is there any way so that I can confirm that restore is successful?

Answer (score 1):

> I have started the restore of the backup but for some reason i have not enable the log and also my session end. So how i will verify that restore was done successfully.

It will almost certainly have *failed*.

Without specific instruction to the contrary, ending your session forcibly kills any and all processes running within that session.

Consider running the restore through the **nohup** command to prevent this:

```
nohup mysql < dump.sql 1>log 2>&1
```

This will allow this process to continue even if your session is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the return value for the command, if 0 then OK else failure.

Put may put it in shell script as follows:

```
 mysql < dump.sql 1>err 2>&1 
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
    echo "dump load failed.";
 fi;
```

or manually run `echo $?` and determine the result.

If you didn't capture the `mysql` exit code, or if your session terminated, you need to manually verify if all the dump contents are properly loaded.

One way to compare it is using `mysqldumpsplitter`: `mysqldumpsplitter --source file.sql --desc > org.txt`. Take a fresh dump from the database with `--no-data` and again run the same `mysqldumpsplitter --source freshdump.sql --desc > new.txt`, then `diff org.txt new.txt`.

See [this blog](https://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script) for more details.